# Asymptotic behavior of roots of an equation involving exponential and logarithm

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, roots, lambert-w

#### Prelude

This Post is a continuation of this [Original Post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3020913/113708). The original problem asked is:

How many solutions does the following equation have:

$$
a^x = \log_a(x) \,,\quad a \in (0,1) \wedge x \in\mathbb{R}^+_0
$$

And already has been answered (see [Claude Leibovici's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3021066/113708) for details).

#### Observations

I found this problem interesting and I numerically investigated it a bit deeper. This led me to another question. Figures below show that such roots exist and are reals:

[image]
[image] 
[image]

And roots can be computed numerically for several values of  $a$:

[image]

My observations, so far, are:

1. All roots must lie in $(0,1)$ because $\log_a(x) > 0 \, \forall x  \in (0,1)$ and $\log_a(x) < 0$ elsewhere, and $a^x > 0 \,\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$;
2. Solving this problem involves complex analysis (such as the use of [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)) but the result will stay in the real domain;
3. A "divergence" point occurs at $(e^{-e},e^{-1})$;
4. Solving the original problem is equivalent to solve (base conversion and Lambert W properties):$$\ln(a) = \frac{W\left(x \ln(x)\right)}{x} = \frac{\ln(x)}{x} \Leftrightarrow a_k = \exp\left[\frac{W_k\left(x \ln(x)\right)}{x}\right]$$
5. Roots become triple when $a < e^{-e}$ (dashed black vertical line, as shown by Claude Leibovici in his answer)
6. Roots have asymptotic behavior, it can be checked in term of $a(x)$ for two branches:

   - one root tends to unity as $a\rightarrow 1$: $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 1} a = 1$ (green curve rightmost);
   - two roots [tend to zero](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim(exp(ln(x)%2Fx),x%3D0)) as $a\rightarrow 0^+$: $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0^+} a = 0$ (green and orange curves leftmost).

#### Questions:

My main questions are:

- <strike>**How can I prove that one root tends to unity when base $a\rightarrow 0^+$ (blue curve leftmost)?**</strike> [By taking the limit of the proper branch](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3025361/113708).
- <strike>Is the point 4 correct?</strike> Investigating the solution using Wolfram Alpha it seems both [Leibovici](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot((x*log(x)%2Flambertw(x*log(x)))%5E(1%2Fx),x%3D0..1) and [my](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot(exp(lambertw(x*log(x))%2Fx),x%3D0..1) expressions are [equivalent](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x*log(x)%2Flambertw(x*log(x)))%5E(1%2Fx)%20%3D%3D%20exp(lambertw(x*log(x))%2Fx). But the first form suffer a huge float arithmetic error with `numpy` library. Anyway they can be plotted using the latter form:

[image]

Side questions are:

- How is called the point where branches diverge?
- Do end of the branches also have a specific name?
- <strike>Can we say that roots are multiple at the "divergence" point? If so, in what sense are they multiple?</strike> Claude Leibovici: Roots are multiple in the sense that three first degrees of Taylor expansion vanishes at $x=e^{-1}$ with $a=e^{-e}$.
- Is the green branch a specific one because it behaves smoothly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Probably not answering the questions but this is too long for comments.*

Considering the function $$f(x)=a^x-\frac{\log (x)}{\log (a)}$$ its derivatives are
$$f^{(n)}(x)=a^x \log^n(a)+(-1)^n \frac{(n-1)!}{x^n\, \log(a)}$$
The first derivative cancels at two points given by 
$$x_1=\frac{W_0\left(\frac{1}{\log (a)}\right)}{\log (a)}\qquad \text{and}\qquad x_2=\frac{W_{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\log (a)}\right)}{\log (a)}$$ which, in the real domain, exist if $\frac{1}{\log (a)}\geq -\frac 1 e$ that is to say if $a \leq e^{-e}$. If this is the case, $f(x_1)<0$ and $f(x_2)>0$ which explains the three roots.

What is interesting is to look at what happens when $a = e^{-e}$. For this value, the solution of $f(x)=0$ is unique $x=\frac 1e$. At this point, the second derivative is also zero and the Taylor expansion is
$$\frac{e^2}{6}  \left(x-\frac{1}{e}\right)^3-\frac{5e^3}{24} 
   \left(x-\frac{1}{e}\right)^4+O\left(\left(x-\frac{1}{e}\right)^5\right)$$ which makes that, at ths point, $x=\frac 1e$ is a triple root of the equation.

On another side, we could also solve the equation for $a$ and its solutions are given by
$$a_1=\left(\frac{x \log (x)}{W_{0}(x \log (x))}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}\qquad \text{and}\qquad a_2=\left(\frac{x \log (x)}{W_{-1}(x \log (x))}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}$$ which do exist if $x \leq \frac 1e$. These two functions are worth to be plotted.

When $x \to 1$ the expansion of $a_1$ is
$$a_1=1+(x-1)-(x-1)^2+\frac{1}{2} (x-1)^3+O\left((x-1)^4\right)$$ and using series reversion
$$x= 1+(a_1-1)+O\left((a_1-1)^2\right)$$ making that if $x\to 0 \implies a_1 \to 0$.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer. I have updated my OP to integrate information you provided. I had problem to plot you expression of $a$ using `numpy` but I succeed with another form (looks like a float error propagation I think it is due to the fractional power that grows quickly as $x \rightarrow 0$). Anyway Wolfram seems to show that both our versions agree.